# Using SELECT Multiple to perform a filtered search

Tags: select, asp-classic

I have searched previous questions and either haven't understood the answer or it was slightly different to my issue.

I manage an Business Management System and this system uses a MS Access Database (MDE file). The system itself is an intranet site using ASP pages and is a repository for all of our processes and procedures, while also providing our continual improvement system.

I have only average programing ability and am limited by not being able to modify the MDE file (except for creating new queries and unlinked tables). I'm trying to enhance the system and have made a few changes but have come to a hurdle which I need help.

There is an advance search for the Improvement area, but currently the search only allows one selection per field, for example, I can search for one of the following "New", "Open", "Completed", or "Closed". The code was originally using "SELECT" and I trialed changing this option to "SELECT Multiple" but the result was searching for all selected fields in each record (if I selected New and Open, it would only return records with both values which was none)

Is there a way to modify multiple select to search for Selection1 OR Selection2, instead of Selection1 AND Selection2. I also tried check boxes and for my purpose these seem more appropriate but I'm getting the same result.

Also the select option looks at a particular table and field to populate the dropdown list, can I get checkboxes to do the same? When I tried the check box option I manually named each option.

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I thought it would be easy to explain what I'm trying to achieve. Work has frozen money for improving the system but still expect me to do something about it, so I'm trying to learn myself.

Thanks for any help,
Leon.

Thanks for replying. I think I understand what you mean by request form. I think I'm having trouble explaining properly as I'm still learning (steep Curve)

To further clarify (I hope), what is happening I've included some of the code.

From the search page:

```
<!--#include file="include.asp"-->

<%  Set cnnSIDB = openConn()
Set rsName = getLogin(cnnSIDB, Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))
Set rsStatus = cnnSIDB.Execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_SIDB_IR_Status")
Set rsExecutive = cnnSIDB.Execute("SELECT * FROM NASPO.dbo.NAS_tblExecutive WHERE vBranchCode = '" & Session("vBranchCode_Select") & "' ORDER BY iSortOrder")
Set rsPerson = cnnSIDB.Execute("SELECT * FROM NASPO.dbo.NAS_vPerson WHERE vBranchCode    = '" & Session("vBranchCode_Select") & "' ORDER BY vLastName, vFirstName")
Set rsPosition = cnnSIDB.Execute("SELECT * FROM v_SIDB_Sponsor WHERE vBranchCode = '" & Session("vBranchCode_Select") & "' ORDER BY vPositionCode")
Set rsCategory = cnnSIDB.Execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_SIDB_IR_Category ORDER BY vCategoryDesc")
Set rsPriority = cnnSIDB.Execute("SELECT vPriority FROM tbl_SIDB_IR_Priority ORDER BY iSortOrder") %>

<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>System Improvement Proposals</TITLE>
<!--#include virtual="/include/menu_include.inc"-->

<SCRIPT language=javascript src="/calendar/calendar1.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="../include/formscripts.js"></script>
<SCRIPT language=javascript>

var cal1;

function setFocus() {
document.fSearchIR.lngIR.focus();
openPage(document.all.Processes_IR, document.all.Processes, ProcessesPic);
}

function showCalendar(objField) {
cal1 = new calendar1(objField);
cal1.year_scroll = true;
cal1.time_comp = false;
cal1.popup();
}


function submitSearchForm() {
var f ;
f = document.forms("fSearchIR") ;
f.vDelegate.value = f.lngDelegate.options[f.lngDelegate.selectedIndex].text ;
f.vOriginator.value = f.lngOriginator.options[f.lngOriginator.selectedIndex].text ;
f.vSponsor.value = f.lngSponsor.options[f.lngSponsor.selectedIndex].text ;
f.vCoord.value = f.lngCoord.options[f.lngCoord.selectedIndex].text ;
f.txtCreatedFrom.value = f.dteCreatedFrom.value;
f.txtCreatedTo.value = f.dteCreatedTo.value;
f.txtTargetFrom.value = f.dteTargetFrom.value;
f.txtTargetTo.value = f.dteTargetTo.value;
f.txtReviewFrom.value = f.dteReviewFrom.value;
f.txtReviewTo.value = f.dteReviewTo.value;
f.submit();
}



function resetForm() {
var f ;
f = document.forms("fSearchIR") ;
document.frames("fSponsorPerson").location.href = "http://<%=Application("HOME")%>/Standing_Instructions/fSponsorPerson.asp?PositionID=0" ;
f.reset() ;
}

function getSponsorPerson() {
document.frames("fSponsorPerson").location.href = "http://<%=Application("HOME")%>/Standing_Instructions/fSponsorPerson.asp?PositionID=" + document.all.lngSponsor.value ;
}

</SCRIPT>
</head>

<BODY topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 bgcolor=white onLoad="setFocus()">

<!--#include virtual="/include/menu.inc"-->

<TABLE class=clsText width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 align=center>
<TR><TD class=clsPageHeading width=20></TD>
<TD class=clsPageHeading valign=top>Search SIP Database</TD>
<TD class=clsPageHeading align=right valign=top>
<INPUT class=clsReturn type=button value="RETURN" onClick="location.href='default_IR.asp'"></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

<BR><BR>
<!-- top of photo frame -->
<TABLE border=0 align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=75% class=clsText>
<TR>
<TD width=22><IMG src="/images/photo_topleft.gif" width=22 height=42></TD>
<TD background="/images/photo_top.gif"><IMG src="/images/photo_top_heading_search.gif" width=260 height=42></TD>
<TD width=30><IMG src="/images/photo_topright.gif" width=30 height=42></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD width=22 background="/images/photo_left.gif"></TD>
<TD valign=top>

<!-- ======================  SEARCH Form starts here ================================= -->



<TABLE border=0 class=clsText width=100% align=center>
<FORM name=fSearchIR action="http://<%=Application("HOME")%>/Standing_Instructions/listIR.asp" method=post>
<INPUT type=hidden name=SEARCH value=1>
<INPUT type=hidden name=listIR_return value="searchIR.asp">
<INPUT type=hidden name=vDelegate>
<INPUT type=hidden name=vOriginator>
<INPUT type=hidden name=vSponsor>
<INPUT type=hidden name=vCoord>
<INPUT type=hidden name=vRelatedArea>
<INPUT type=hidden name=txtCreatedFrom>
<INPUT type=hidden name=txtCreatedTo>
<INPUT type=hidden name=txtTargetFrom>
<INPUT type=hidden name=txtTargetTo>
<INPUT type=hidden name=txtReviewFrom>
<INPUT type=hidden name=txtReviewTo>

********* some more code *************

<TR>
<TD colspan=3></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD width=10>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>SIP #</TD>
<TD><INPUT class=clsText type=text name=lngIR size=11></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD width=10>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>Subject</TD>
<TD><INPUT class=clsText type=text name=vSubject size=40></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD width=10>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>Status</TD>
<TD><SELECT name=vStatus class=clsText>
<OPTION value="" selected></OPTION>
<%  Do Until rsStatus.EOF %>
<OPTION value="<%=rsStatus("vStatus")%>"><%=rsStatus("vStatusDesc")%></OPTION>
<%      rsStatus.MoveNext
Loop %>
</SELECT></TD></TR>
```

Then on the next page "ListIR.asp" this is the code:

```
<!--#include file="include.asp"-->
<%  listIR_return = Request.Form("listIR_return")
If Not listIR_return > "" Then listIR_return = "default_IR.asp"

Set cnnSIDB = openConn()
Set rsName = getLogin(cnnSIDB, Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))
Set rsIR = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If Request.Form("SEARCH") = 1 Then

If Request.Form("lngIR") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "lngIR = " & Request.Form("lngIR")
strDesc = strDesc & "SIP # = " & Request.Form("lngIR")
End If

If Request.Form("vSubject") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vSubject LIKE '%" & Request.Form("vSubject") & "%'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Subject LIKE '" & Request.Form("vSubject") & "'"
End If

If Request.Form("vSICode") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vSICode = '" & Request.Form("vSICode") & "'"
strDesc = strDesc & "SICode = '" & Request.Form("vSICode") & "'"
End If

If Request.Form("lngDelegate") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "lngDelegate = " & Request.Form("lngDelegate")
strDesc = strDesc & "Delegate = " & Request.Form("vDelegate")
End If

If Request.Form("lngOriginator") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "lngOriginator = " & Request.Form("lngOriginator")
strDesc = strDesc & "Originator = " & Request.Form("vOriginator")
End If

If Request.Form("vOrigArea") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vOriginatorExecutive = '" & Request.Form("vOrigArea") & "'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Originating Area = '" & Request.Form("vOrigArea") & "'"
End If

If Request.Form("vExecutiveCode") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vDelegateExecutive = '" & Request.Form("vExecutiveCode") & "'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Related Area = '" & Request.Form("vExecutiveCode") & "'"
End If

If Request.Form("vPriority") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vPriority = '" & Request.Form("vPriority") & "'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Priority = '" & Request.Form("vPriority") & "'"
End If

If Request.Form("lngSponsor") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "lngSponsor = " & Request.Form("lngSponsor")
strDesc = strDesc & "Sponsor = " & Request.Form("vSponsor")
End If

If Request.Form("lngCoord") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "lngCoord = " & Request.Form("lngCoord")
strDesc = strDesc & "Coord = " & Request.Form("vCoord")
End If

If Request.Form("vStatus") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vStatus = '" & Request.Form("vStatus") & "'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Status = '" & Request.Form("vStatus") & "'"
End If

*********** at the end of this page it has this code ********

<%  If strDesc > "" Then %>

<TABLE border=0 width=100% class=clsVerdana9>
<TR height=7><TD></TD></TR>
<TR><TD><B>Search Criteria: <FONT color=red><%=strDesc%></FONT></B></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

<%  End If %>


<%  If rsIR.EOF Then %>
<P class=clsText align=center>
There were no System Improvement Proposals matching your search criteria.
<BR><BR>
Please return to the <A href="http://<%=Application("HOME")%>/Standing_Instructions/searchIR.asp" class=bluered>Search Page</A> to refine your search.
</P>
<TABLE border=0 width=100%>
<%  Else  %>
<TABLE border=0 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 class=clsVerdana8>
<TR height=107>
<TD colspan=8 height="107"></TD>
</TR>
<TR bgcolor="#CCCCCC" height=1>
<TD colspan=8></TD>
</TR>
<TR bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
<TD width=40>SIP#</TD>
<TD>Subject</TD>
<TD width=157>Delegate</TD>
<td width=114>Priority</td>
<td width=60 align=right>Created</td>
<td width=60 align=right>Target</td>
<TD width=50 align=center>Status</TD>
<TD width=60 align=right>Date</TD>
</TR>
<TR bgcolor="#CCCCCC" height=1>
<TD colspan=8></TD>
</TR>
<%  bAltRow = true
Do Until rsIR.EOF %>
<FORM name="fViewIR_<%=rsIR("lngIR")%>" action="http://<%=Application("HOME")%>/Standing_Instructions/viewIR.asp" method=post target="_parent">
<INPUT type=hidden name=viewIR_return value="listIR.asp">
<INPUT type=hidden name=listIR_return value="<%=listIR_return%>">
<INPUT type=hidden name=strWhere value="<%=strWhere%>">
<INPUT type=hidden name=strDesc value="<%=strDesc%>">
<INPUT type=hidden name="lngIR" value="<%=rsIR("lngIR")%>">
</FORM>
<%  If bAltRow Then
Response.Write "<TR class=clsText>"
Else
Response.Write "<TR class=clsText2>"
End If
bAltRow = Not bAltRow %>
<TD><%=rsIR("lngIR")%></TD>
<TD><A href="javascript:fViewIR_<%=rsIR("lngIR")%>.submit()" class=bluered><%=rsIR("vSubject")%></A></TD>
<TD width="157"><A href="/employee.asp?ID=<%=rsIR("lngDelegate")%>" class=navyred><font size="1"><%=rsIR("vDelegate")%></font></A<</TD>
<TD width="114"><font size="1"><%=rsIR("vPriority")%></font></TD>
<TD align=right><font size="1"><%=formatDate(rsIR("dteCreated"),2)%></font></TD>
<TD align=right><font size="1"><%=formatDate(rsIR("dteTarget"),2)%></font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="1"><%=rsIR("vStatus")%></font></TD>
<TD align=right><font size="1"><%=formatDate(rsIR("dteStatus"),2)%></font></TD>
</TR>
<TR bgcolor="#CCCCCC" height=1>
<TD colspan=8></TD>
</TR>
<% rsIR.MoveNext
Loop
End If %>
</TABLE>
</td></tr>

</table>
</body>
<%
rsName.Close
Set rsName = Nothing
rsIR.Close
Set rsIR = Nothing
cnnSIDB.Close
Set cnnSIDB = Nothing
%>
</html>
```

Sorry if this is way too long, or if I have stuffed up the formatting. Any help would be appreciated.

Update -

Hi, I've been studying the two pages and think I understand what they're doing. The first page is collecting the user inputs and the second page, mainly the the area that looks like the last block of code that I posted last time, gets the user input and adds it to this string further down the page.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM v_SIDB_IR_ALL " & strWhere & " ORDER BY lngSortOrder, lngIR DESC"
```

I've played around with the IN and AND options and have moved the vStatus code to the bottom or top of the code (thinking it may not be working due to the "IN" being placed at the wrong end/area of the string) but it results in either a page error that doesn't load the page, or a page with my initial issue or a page returning everything.

I'm not sure where to go now

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the pages to do what I needed, though I never did solve my initial issue with using multiple select. Instead I used an alternate method. As I mentioned in my last post, the user inputs on the search page get combined and added to a record set connection string on the search result page.

I tried (and failed) to split the result of the multiple select string that I added to the search page and feed that into the connection string of the search result page. So my alternate method was to create check boxes and add those results to the connection string.

One the search page I replaced:

```
<TD><SELECT name=vStatus class=clsText>
    <OPTION value="" selected></OPTION>
        <% Do Until rsStatus.EOF %>
        <OPTION value="<%=rsStatus("vStatus")%>"><%=rsStatus("vStatusDesc")%></OPTION>
    <%  rsStatus.MoveNext
    Loop %>
</SELECT></TD>
```

with this

```
<TD>
<INPUT type=checkbox name=nStat value="NEW"> New
<INPUT type=checkbox name=oStat value="OPEN"> Open
<INPUT type=checkbox name=coStat value="COMPL"> Completed
<INPUT type=checkbox name=clStat value="CLOSE"> Closed
</TD>
```

And on the search result page I replaced:

```
If Request.Form("vStatus") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
strDesc = strDesc & " AND "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vStatus = '" & Request.Form("vStatus") & "'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Status = '" & Request.Form("vStatus") & "'"
End If
```

with this new code, I also moved this block from the middle of the code to the top so the connection string would have this section at the start:

```
If Request.Form("nStat") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " OR "
strDesc = strDesc & " OR "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vStatus = 'NEW'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Status = 'NEW'"
End If

If Request.Form("oStat") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " OR "
strDesc = strDesc & " OR "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vStatus = 'OPEN'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Status = 'OPEN'"
End If

If Request.Form("coStat") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " OR "
strDesc = strDesc & " OR "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vStatus = 'COMPL'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Status = 'COMPL'"
End If

If Request.Form("clStat") > "" Then
If strWhere > "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & " OR "
strDesc = strDesc & " OR "
End If
strWhere = strWhere & "vStatus = 'CLOSE'"
strDesc = strDesc & "Status = 'CLOSE'"
End If
```

The this methods seems to work and I'm happy with it, but that's because the number of possible status' is small. It would of been nice to have the multiple select working as some of the other areas "Delegate", "Originator" etc have over 500 people to choose from. Nevertheless, I have learned heaps, thanks for your help, especially Ravi.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think by SELECT Multiple you're referring to the  tag in your HTML code that now lets you select more than one option from your earlier drop down list which allowed for only one selection.

*(Let me assume you're fetching orders and passing order status values for the rest of the answer.)*

You need to understand that this is just a UI change done on the front and has little bearing on the actual query that is getting fired against your database and finally determines which records get fetched from the database.

With that said, this UI change is also required to let you pass multiple status values (that need to be matched) to the `.asp` script that interacts with your MS Access database file. Check your HTML page again for a `<form>` tag whose `action` attribute would let you know the `.asp` file that actually fires the database query.

This file would probably have a SELECT SQL query that after substitution with the status value passed from the UI would look something like

```
SELECT * FROM orders_table WHERE order_status LIKE 'new'
```

To make your query fetch records that match multiple order status values you would need something like

```
SELECT * FROM orders_table WHERE order_status IN ('new', 'open', 'completed')
```

*(Please note that this is just to indicate what the query should become post substitution with status values NOT how they should actually look like in the code.)*

If you seem to be lost with all this just find your `.asp` script and post its relevant code here and somebody would definitely be able to point you in the right direction.

***EDIT**:*
Here's a couple of basic online tutorials that should help you with the fundamentals. Perhaps, with a better understanding you would be able to edit your question and present your requirements with more clarity. Hope this helps.

> [HTML Forms](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/forms/)
>   
>     [Connecting to an Access Database using Classic ASP](http://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/connecting-to-an-access-database.htm)
>   
>   [SQL SELECT statement](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-select-statement.htm)
>   [Using LIKE and IN with SQL SELECT statement](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-like-in-operators.htm)

Comment: Thanks I think I understand what you mean by request form. I think I'm having trouble explaining properly as I'm still learning (steep Curve)

Comment: @Leon, I've added links to some tutorials that should help you with quick understanding of the basics that's needed here. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have re-read you initial response and think I'm understanding more. This is also due to  spending the last few weeks fixing up less complex issues with other pages and thus increasing my grasp. I will have another go tomorrow and see.